# Ansible prevent the stdout to show on output logs

Tags: ansible

I'm having this task where I'm trying to cat the file with password and append it to another file via ansible stdout.

```
- name: get  password value
  shell: "cat {{ playbook_dir }}/../PASSWORD/PASSWORD.txt"
  register: PASSWORD_VALUE
- debug: var=PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout

- name: echo PASSWORD password value to another file
  shell: "echo {{ PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout }} > PASSWORD_VALUE.txt"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../PASSWORD"
```

However when ansible is executed it shows the passwords **PASSWORD_NG_POGING_LALAKI** from logs.

```
    TASK [get  password value] **********************************************
    changed: [localhost]

    TASK [debug] ************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout": "PASSWORD_NG_POGING_LALAKI"
    }

    TASK [echo PASSWORD password value to another file] *********************
    changed: [localhost]
```

**Is there a way where I can prevent the PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout hide its value from the logs?**

Answer (score -1):

Solved it, I just added **no_log: true** below the debug line

```
- name: get  password value
  shell: "cat {{ playbook_dir }}/../PASSWORD/PASSWORD.txt"
  register: PASSWORD_VALUE
- debug: var=PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout
  no_log: true

- name: echo PASSWORD password value to another file
  shell: "echo {{ PASSWORD_VALUE.stdout }} > PASSWORD_VALUE.txt"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../PASSWORD"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TASK [get  password value] **********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [echo PASSWORD password value to another file] *********************
changed: [localhost]
```